# Animate an image inside a container DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking to animate an image inside a container DIV so the image automatically when the page loads starts moving left/right + up/down inside the DIV. Do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS3 transitions](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/animations/) or [jQuery Animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

you need a client side scripting lanuage like javascript

you may want to use jquery to do the animation you are talking about

http://jquery.com/

i know you can do it using jquery i already did it